# While until echo "success " linux

Tags: linux, while-loop, do-while

i,m trying to make a while loop in my script, until "success" comes back on the console.

My try:

```
while [ -n $(eval "node $srcPATH/webrcon.js $msg 'world.rendermap'") ]; do
    sleep 5s
done
exit
echo "Next code after the while loop after get the success echo on console"
```

After exit the script going on, but he freeze and do nothing, also no exit.

Comment: `exit` terminates the script, nothing after that should be executed.

Comment: Why are you using `eval`?

Comment: You're never checking whether the output of the `node` command is `success`. You just test whether the output is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop continues as long as the command produces any output. You need to compare with `success`.

```
while [ "$(eval "node $srcPATH/webrcon.js $msg 'world.rendermap'")" != "success" ]; do
    sleep 5s
done
```